# Can two < symbols occur consecutively for HTML tag?

Tags: php, html, regex, wordpress

**Question: can in HTML the expression `<<` exists where the first `<` is the opening of an HTML tag?**

The origin of my question is the following one. I run a [mathematics website](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/) based on WordPress. As you can imagine, there is a lot of `<` and `>` in the posts (mathematics inequalities).

For long posts, I use the "Continue reading" capability offered by WordPress. When several posts are displayed with "Continue reading" capability, using `<!--more-->` tag, the WordPress function [force_balance_tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/force_balance_tags) is used in order to properly balance HTML tags that maybe spread over the `<!--more-->` tag.

There is a bug in the PHP `force_balance_tags` function. For example the HMTL code

`< <strong>We</strong>`

produces the output

`< <strong>We`

which is wrong as the `<bold>` HTML tag is not closed properly.

I'm trying to fix the bug... but I'm coming from far away (FORTRAN programming 25 years ago ;-)). `force_balance_tags` is using regular expressions.

Therefore my initial question. The root cause of the bug is probably that `force_balance_tags` is looking to find a `>` symbol to close the `<` initial one which is not interpreted as the inequality symbol.

*Note: I found a workaround by changing the `<` symbols by the Latex `\le` in my posts. But by curiosity, I would be interested to correct `force_balance_tags`!*

Comment: Why not using &lt; or &#60;? Use "<" only to start an element.

Comment: @JeroenHeier Yes, this is what I did as a workaround. But I'm interested to fix `force_balance_tags`... for the fun!

Comment: `<` is reserved in HTML so if you want anyone to actually see a `<` on a page you need to print the equivalent [HTML entity character](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it can not. HTML uses the syntax of XML, where `<` notes an element. The name of an element can not contain the character `<`.

Read the paragraph "XML Naming Rules" here: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp

Comment: HTML is not XML. It just is not, so _just_ linking to the xml naming scheme is not useful here. While the answer is correct and the naming is indeed invalid for HTML as well, it is just not true that HTML is XML.

Comment: Not trying to be pedantic about it, but you should not try and fit the XML in there. HTML uses the HTML syntax. XHTML is an application of XML, this is true, but HTML just isn't. You can do things in the XML syntax you can't in HTML (e.g. namespacing) and you can do things in HTML you can't do in XML. Check w3c, (not w3schools), for instance: https://w3c.github.io/html/introduction.html#html-vs-xhtml
linking to the xml naming scheme is meaningless here, even if the naming scheme in HTML is similar.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug. Having multiple tag openers (`< <`) is invalid markup. Invalid markup is something that you should always try to avoid; even if it does render correctly in some or all browsers, it's not guaranteed. Wordpress's `force_balance_tags` is a case where it breaks.

Since your site requires characters like this often, as you said, you should run the offending sections through a function which will replace the html characters `<`, `>` with their html entity equivalents, `&lt;`, `&gt;`

Here's an example in php, using [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
str_replace(["<", ">"], ["&lt;", "&gt;"], $mathRelatedContent);
```

With this, however, the problem will come up that you can no longer use direct html markup in your posts. Take a look at adding an alternative markup along with the html escaping (think something similar to the `How to Format` section when posting a question on Stack Overflow!)